# Термин или словосочетание?

Tags: орфография

Термины "**вышеуказанный, вышеизложенный, нижеперечисленный"** пишутся слитно, но сохраняют ли они слитное написание **при наличии пояснительных слов**, например: вышеуказанный мной адрес, вышеизложенный мною материал?

Судя по Интернету, на зависимые слова никто внимания не обращает, но, может быть, **это исключения**, "единичные слитные написания" (по Розенталю)?

**Сравнить**: малознакомые места, глубокоуважаемый человек, мало знакомые нам места, глубоко уважаемый всеми человек.

Comment: Почему термины-то?

Comment: У Розенталя есть эта тема: наречие и прилагательное или терминологически сложное слово, там сравниваются варианты вида "малоисследованные проблемы или мало исследованные наукой проблемы".

Comment: Но "вышеуказанный" и прочие – не термины.

Comment: Ну, можно назвать их устойчивыми формами, которые используются  в деловой  и научной литературе.  Важно то, что они, как и термины, получены сращением наречия и прилагательного и под влиянием зависимых слов распадаются на исходные составляющие, например: глубокоуважаемый (обращение) и глубоко уважаемый всеми человек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

§ 39. СЛОЖНЫЕ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНЫЕ
1. Пишутся слитно:
сложные прилагательные, образованные из сочетаний слов, по своему значению подчиненных одно другому …. по способу примыкания(легкораненый ← легко ранить), (выше указанный - указать выше)
     3. У многих сложных прилагательных терминологического характера в качестве первой части используются слова:ниже-; выше-: вышеуказанный;
В тех случаях, когда каждая часть сложного слова может употребляться самостоятельно, слитное написание сложного прилагательного объясняется тем, что первая часть (широко-, много-, сильно-, ниже-,выше- и т. п.) не выступает в роли самостоятельного члена предложения, поэтому перестановка частей сложного слова невозможна без изменения его терминологического характера: глубокоуважаемый, нижеподписавшиеся и т. п.
4. При наличии пояснительных слов обычно образуется свободное словосочетание (наречие и прилагательное или причастие), а не терминологическое сложное слово. Ср.: вышеуказанный недостаток – указанный выше в перечне недостаток; густонаселённые районы — густо населённые беженцами трущобы;
 Играет роль также порядок слов: сложное прилагательное, как правило, предшествует второму существительному, а словосочетание обычно следует за ним; ср.: скоропортящиеся продукты — продукты, скоро портящиеся в летнее время.
Запомните: в сложных словах ставится одно ударение (иногда с побочным ударением на первой основе):  малоприспосо́бленный,  а в словосочетаниях два самостоятельных ударения: ма́ло  приспосо́бленный  к засухам.(аналогично и в слове вышеука́занный ) 
Д Розенталь. Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация
Таким образом, сложные прилагательные терминологического характера "вышеуказанный, вышеизложенный, нижеперечисленный" пишутся слитно и сохраняют слитное написание при наличии пояснительных слов.

Comment: Эта статья  Розенталя мне известна, но почему вы делаете вывод о том, что при наличии пояснительных слов  мы имеем слитное написание "вышеизложенный мною" и т.д. Розенталь  приводит только один такой пример "экономически слаборазвитые страны" в качестве единичных написаний.

Comment: Насколько я Вас поняла, Sibylla, Вы ведёте речь о терминах. А Розенталь подчёркивает, что при наличии пояснительных слов, данные "терминологические сложные слова" (как они названы в статье) перестают быть таковыми. Кроме того, наличие одного ударения в слове позволяет сделать следующий вывод.

Comment: Мне понравился Ваш вопрос. Я тоже размышляла над чем-то аналогичным, но не могла сформулировать.